# React Native: get native module size

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native, native-module

After wrapped a native module with view container, how to set the size of the view container in RN so that the native module would not be cut by the boundary of the view container in RN?

Also, is it possible to set view size of parent depending on its children's views in objective-c/swift?